# Not able to install tensorflow for Python 2.7 in windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pycharm

I am aware that tensorflow is available for Python 3.5 and above but is  there any possibility that tensorflow can be installed for python 2.7 using cmd in windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to do quite some work. Specifically you need to build tensorflow yourself and [Installing TensorFlow from Sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) states:

> We don't officially support building TensorFlow on Windows; however, you may try to build TensorFlow on Windows if you don't mind using the highly experimental [Bazel on Windows](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html) or [TensorFlow CMake build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.12/tensorflow/contrib/cmake).

I would highly recommend you try to use python 3.5 instead if at all possible. If you use conda, you could create a new conda environment with

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

and install tensorflow inside that environment using

```
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```